# Update dbEnitity columns values from List<MyClass> without usinf two foreach loops

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, list, entity-framework

I have a class - PairedValues.cs, code below:

```
public class PairedValues
{
    public string FileName { get; set; }
    public DateTime StartTime { get; set; }
    public DateTime EndTime { get; set; }

    public PairedValues(string val1, DateTime val2, DateTime val3)
    {
        FileName = val1;
        StartTime = val2;
        EndTime = val3;
    }

    public PairedValues() { }
}
```

In my other method I am adding filename, start time and end time to the List:

```
pairedValues.Add(new PairedValues(name, startTime, endTime));
```

Now, I have a database which has similar columns like name, startTime, EndTime, I need to update this table from the pairedValues, so I am looping through the list of pairedValues and trying to do below:

```
 foreach (var val in pairedValues)
 {           
     listOfFiles = GetListOfFiles()
         .Where(e => e.fileName == val.FileName)
         .ToList();
 }
```

I want to update the values for each columns in listofFiles from pairedValues, I can do that using another foreach, but how to avoid that? Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Save to database code below:

```
  public void SaveDetails(List<MyDbTable> listOfFiles)
    {
        _Entity.MyTable.AddRange(listOfFiles);

        try
        {
            _Entity.SaveChanges();
        }
        catch (DbUpdateException ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why is the central code to the question (the supposed second for loop) missing from the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood correctly

you have a list of pairedValues and for each paired value file name `GetListOfFiles` method may return one or more records which are type of MyTable

in this case you need to use a nested loop or if you want you can use Linq

1-Nested Loop

```
 foreach (var val in pairedValues)
 {           
        foreach(var file in GetListOfFiles().Where(x=>x.fileName == 
         val.FileName).ToList())
         {
            //Create new record here (we don't know the property names)
            var newRecord = new MyTable();
            newRecord.FileName = file.Filename // or whater 

             //TODO Now add the new record to 
              _Entity.MyTable.Add(newRecord);
         }

 }
_Entity.SaveChanges();  // save outside the loop to reduce the database roundtrips..
```

2-Linq

```
pairedValues.forech(x=> {
    x.GetListOfFiles()
     .Where(e => e.fileName == val.FileName)
     .ToList().foreach(y=> {
          //Create new record here (we don't know the property names)
          var newRecord = new MyTable();
          newRecord.FileName = y.Filename // or whater 

         //TODO Now add the new record to 
          _Entity.MyTable.Add(newRecord);
      });
});
```

Hope this helps!

P.S I have't used a compiler writing the code so excuse any typo errors..

Comment: @Licentia-  Thanks for your help.